# NameError: name '..' is not defined in Jupyter notebook when loading external script module

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have a file called "helper_functions.py":

```
import numpy as np

def arr_to_mat(arr):
    arr_copy = arr.copy()
    arr_len = arr_copy.size
    n = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(arr_len)))
    arr_copy.resize((n, n))
    return arr_copy
```

Which I call in a large jupyter notebook, where numpy has been loaded in at the beginning too. I then call the function, but it doesn't seem to load in numpy in that external script and functions:

```
import numpy as np
from helper_functions import arr_to_mat

m = np.random.rand(1, 25)

m_arr = arr_to_mat(m)
```

Then error:

```
~\helper_functions.py in arr_to_mat(arr)
     40     arr_copy = arr.copy()
     41     arr_len = arr_copy.size
---> 42     n = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(arr_len)))
     43     arr_copy.resize((n, n))
     44     return arr_copy

NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

Other functions have been working fine calling them from the external file, except this one doesn't work. Not sure why that is and I can't see exactly why either.

I will have more functions that have similar methods of importing modules and being called externally later, so I would like to have a solution for the futue to make sure I don't make this mistake again.

Many similar posts on here describe the issue being the function being called before the module has been loaded in, but this has not been the case for me as I both load in the module before the function, and the module has been loaded in in the jupyter notebook already as well and has been working.

The other answers simply say to restart the kernel and then it should work, but that didn't work either. The issue is still present.